# Load adds from JobAdder on Nuxt page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt website/blog where I'd like to render some job ads on one particular page so not changing the route structure and creating children pages for each job posted.
This pen gives an idea of what I'm trying to do:

```
<div id="ja-jobs-widget"></div>
<script>
    var _jaJobsSettings = {
        key: "bbhc36kiqfoudkoc4yd7qaihf4",
        jobListSettings: {
            titleIsLink: false
        },
        jobDetailsSettings: {
            showBulletPoints: false
        },
        applicationFormSettings: {
            useExternalApplicationForm: true
        }
    };
</script>
<script src="//jobadder.com/widgets/v1/jobs.min.js"></script>
```